# Is P ^ ¬(Q ^ R) in DNF?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

¬(Q ^ R) can be (¬Q v ¬R) according to De Morgan’s Law

So we get P ^ ¬Q v ¬R which can be written as

(P ^ ¬Q) v  (¬R) which is in DNF

So can I say that P ^ ¬(Q ^ R) is in DNF?

Comment: In addition to the information in the answers, note that $P\land(\neg Q\lor\neg R)$ is not equivalent to $(P\land\neg Q)\lor(\neg R)$.

Answer (score 1):

DNF (and CNF, and NNF, and ..) are about the *syntactical* nature of the expression.  Once you start rewriting the expression into a different one, even if it is logically (i.e *semantically*) equivalent, it is no longer that same syntactical expression. So, just because the logical equivalent of some statement is in DNF does not mean that the original is in DNF.

Answer (score 0):

Every formula can be converted to DNF, but the fact that a formula can be converted to DNF does not imply that that formula is DNF itself

So, (P ^ ¬(Q ^ R)) is not DNF, but ((P ^ ¬Q) v (P ^ ¬R)) is DNF